# URL para un M3U8 audio mas video

Tags: video, audio, ts, hls

tengo una dirección m3u8 de un video de tercero: https://wisp.cdn.rcs.net.ar/mnp/fx_hls/playlist.m3u8

con este armado:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="Audio 0 (es)",LANGUAGE="es",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,**URI="audio_4/playlist.m3u8"**
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="Audio 1 (en)",LANGUAGE="en",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,**URI="audio_5/playlist.m3u8"**
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1775892,CODECS="avc1.42001f",AUDIO="audio"
**track_0_1500/playlist.m3u8**
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=636607,CODECS="avc1.42001e",AUDIO="audio"
**track_1_500/playlist.m3u8**
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2736607,CODECS="avc1.42001f",AUDIO="audio"
**track_2_2500/playlist.m3u8**
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=6300000,CODECS="avc1.420028",AUDIO="audio"
**track_3_6000/playlist.m3u8**
```

Tiene dos pistas de audio, español e ingles, yo quiero que esté en ingles.
El problema es que tiene dos niveles ya que si en la URL pongo "track_2_2500/playlist.m3u8" no sale la pista de audio, y si pongo "audio_5/playlist.m3u8" no sale la imagen

**¿Cómo debo escribir la URL para que me seleccione la imagen y el sonido que yo quiero?**

Comment: pudiste dar alguna solucion ? tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, borra la URL original del m3u8 sino con el crawler la van a cambiar mas adelante, segundo para poder hacer lo que necesitas, usa ffmpeg y retransmiti

ffmpeg -v 0 -loglevel 0 -user_agent "VLC/3.0.18 LibVLC/3.0.18" -i https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/output.mpd -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 4 -hls_wrap 8 /www/wwwroot/xxxxxxxx/index.m3u8

donde tiene el -c copy podes utilizar el map para extraer el aduio y transmitir como tu quieras, saludos!